# what is difference between PDK and SDK?

Tags: embedded, software-design

means sdk and pdk contains code or executable and libraries. 
but what are the things which are present in one but not in other?

PDK = Product / Platform Development Kit.
SDK = Software Development Kit.

Answer (score 1):

The PDK contains more or less everything which is needed for creating the firmware for a device: sources and/or binaries of OS components, and lots of tools...
The SDK contains a subset of these components, things which are required for creating software for an already existing device.

Comment: Can we say Ubuntu is PDK but GCC is just a SDK?

Comment: No! Ubunt or GNC are OS based on Linus... PDK and SDK ARE a set of software development tools that allows the creation of applications for a certain software package, software framework, hardware platform, computer system, video game console, operating system, or similar development platform.

Answer (score 1):

They are not precise technical terms and are probably used variably by marketing departments.  You should not be selecting a product in whether it is called an PDK or SDK but rather on the functionality it provides.

What some may rather grandly refer to as an SDK or PDK others might perhaps more transparently simply refer to as a library. I would expect an SDK or PDK perhaps to include extensive documentation, examples, and support tools perhaps however.